# What's the difference between the Stack Exchange API and the Stack Overflow API?

Tags: support, api, meta

I heard about the Stack Overflow API. Is there a Stack Overflow API available. Or is it the same as the Stack Exchange API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They are one and the same.**
When the API was [first announced <sup>(March 31st, 2010)</sup>](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/), it was temporarily called the "Stack Overflow API" -- even though Jeff said that the API would be "for *all* the trilogy sites".

Two month's later, [when stackapps.com and the public beta were announced](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/), the official name was already ***Stack Exchange API***. There is no separate API just for Stack Overflow.